# When to call Google plus Silent Authentication in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I've `authenticated` with Google plus by `fast-app-switch.` I've seen **silent authentication** with google plus sdk.  I want to implement silent authentication with my app from second time onwards. That is, if user try to sign in by first time, I'll redirect with safari to authenticate(now I've done). But Second time, I just call silent authentication by checking some criteria like authentication token is whether expired or some other condition.

Pseudo code ..

```
if (....what condition...)
   [signIn trySilentAuthentication];
```

Suggest me **how to check this condition** and call `slientAuthentication`?

**Note:** I've seen this question[[QA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209850/google-plus-authentication),[QA2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123341/google-plus-sdk-not-refreshing-token-ios),[QA3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826190/issue-with-google-plus-login-in-ios), but All are told about authentication, but not about silent authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found by doing some practices. You can see below code.

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]hasAuthInKeychain])
{
    if (![signIn trySilentAuthentication])//because some time, it may expired 
        [self initialAuthentication];
}
else
{
   [self initialAuthentication];
}
```

Comment: Mani, how well does this work if the previous authentication was revoked by the user?  Does it still initiate the non-silent authentication process?  The documentation in the header for trySilentAuthentication suggests that method will return YES even if authentication was revoked.